# numpy intersect1d unexpected keyword argument 'return_indices'

Tags: python, numpy

Does anyone understand what I am doing wrong with the numpy intersect1d function ?

```
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 6])
xy, x_ind, y_ind = np.intersect1d(x, y, return_indices=True)
```

and I get this output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: intersect1d() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_indices'
```

I am using Python 3.6

Thanks

Comment: You probably need to update NumPy to `1.15.0`, when the parameter `return_indices` was introduced.

Comment: That was the reason. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not a problem with your Python version but the Numpy version**. I executed your code with a perfectly reasonable result i.e. it did not generate the error.

```py
import numpy as np 
x = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 4])
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 6])
xy, x_ind, y_ind = np.intersect1d(x, y, return_indices=True)

print(xy)
print(x_ind)
print(y_ind)

>>
[1 2 4]
[0 2 4]
[1 0 2]
```